# Custom WordPress widget is wrapping all other widgets below it

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I am trying to write a custom widget to display our teamspeak server info. This is what I have so far:

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Site Plugin for RealmReborn.co
Description: Site specific code changes for RealmReborn.co
*/
/* Start Adding Functions Below this Line */


// Creating the widget 
class wpb_widget extends WP_Widget {

function __construct() {
parent::__construct(
// Base ID of your widget
'wpb_widget', 

// Widget name will appear in UI
__('WPBeginner Widget', 'wpb_widget_domain'), 

// Widget description
array( 'description' => __( 'Sample widget based on WPBeginner Tutorial', 'wpb_widget_domain' ), ) 
);
}

// Creating widget front-end
// This is where the action happens
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
$title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
// before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
echo $args['before_widget'];
if ( ! empty( $title ) )
echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];

// This is where you run the code and display the output
?>

<iframe src="http://cache.www.gametracker.com/components/html0/?host=tsserver.co:9987&bgColor=333333&fontColor=CCCCCC&titleBgColor=222222&titleColor=FF9900&borderColor=555555&linkColor=FFCC00&borderLinkColor=222222&showMap=0&currentPlayersHeight=220&showCurrPlayers=1&showTopPlayers=0&showBlogs=0&width=265" 
 frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="265" height="408"></iframe>

<?php

}

// Widget Backend 
public function form( $instance ) {
if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
$title = $instance[ 'title' ];
}
else {
$title = __( 'New title', 'wpb_widget_domain' );
}
// Widget admin form
?>
<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
</p>
<?php 
}

// Updating widget replacing old instances with new
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
$instance = array();
$instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
return $instance;
}
} // Class wpb_widget ends here

// Register and load the widget
function wpb_load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'wpb_widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_load_widget' );



/* Stop Adding Functions Below this Line */

// Creating the widget 

?>
```

I got this code from a wordpress help site and tried to follow the instructions but I'm doing something wrong.

My site is realmreborn.co and I am trying to display the widget on the right side.

You will notice that the Teamspeak widget is wrapping all of the widgets below it on the right side:

[image]

I do not know what I did wrong, I've tried to make adjustments to the code but nothing I seem to do seems to fix it. Did I miss a bracket or not implement something correctly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a total guess but maybe you need to do a `echo $args['after_widget'];` just before the closing brace after the iframe.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think something wrong with html, check all tags are closed, check for `echo $args['after_widget'];` - I don't see it in code. It's all markup, some fixed and it would be all right)